# Errors when I run Spark in Intellij on Ubuntu

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

When I run the code below I get an error that points to the line indicated by the comment. I have brought in the JAR files for Spark. As I write the code the suggestions arise for how the Spark code can be writin, so the IDE seems to recognize the Spark libary. This is written in Scala and I am new to both Scala and Spark. Otherwise, Scala runs fine in the IDE.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Spark {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val logFile = "/home/thomaswolff/ubuntu/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/LICENSE"
    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Simple Application").getOrCreate()
    val logData = spark.read.textFile(logFile).cache()
    val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()
    val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count()
    println(s"Lines with a: $numAs, Lines with a b: $numBs")
    spark.stop()
  }

}
```

Here are the errors that occur when I run the code in Intellij:

```
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed Oct 8, 2019 5:51:42 PM
[IJ]sbt:ScalaSpark_1> all 
{file:/home/thomaswolff/IdeaProjects/ScalaSpark_1/}scalaspark_1/products 
{file:/home/thomaswolff/IdeaProjects/ScalaSpark_1/}scalaspark_1/test:products
[info] Compiling 4 Scala sources to 
/home/thomaswolff/IdeaProjects/ScalaSpark_1/target/scala-2.13/classes ...
[error] /home/thomaswolff/IdeaProjects/ScalaSpark_1/src/main/scala/Spark.scala:1:12: object 
apache is not a member of package org
[error] import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
[error]            ^
[error] /home/thomaswolff/IdeaProjects/ScalaSpark_1/src/main/scala/Spark.scala:6:17: not 
found: value SparkSession
[error]     val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Simple Application").getOrCreate()
```

An update: I installed an older version of Intellij 2018.2 and loaded the JAR's just as before but now I am getting this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Spark
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Spark
```

Comment: Which version of Scala plugin and Intellij are you using?

Comment: The Intellij version is 2019.2.3. Hold on for the Scala version

Comment: Scala version is: Scala code runner version 2.11.12

Comment: Something you can try quickly is to try with older Intellij IDEs. You can install *JetBrain ToolBox* and use it to quickly test with other versions. I had some success doing this. Apparently Scala plugin in the newest version is not all the way compatible with spark.

Comment: Also make sure your build.sbt fetches everything without any error.

Comment: @jrook would I go into the sbt settings to do that?

Comment: When I do a build I get the same error

Comment: Can you share your `build.sbt` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem. My build.sbt was not correctly set up. Here it is below:

```
name := "sbt_spark_scala"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

val sparkVersion = "2.2.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-graphx" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % sparkVersion,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion % "provided"
)
```

This youtube video helped me a lot: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nYLCoq7PkVs